# http.get api request is calling twice on initial page load

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm using the angular universal.

Once i call the api request form on initial page load, it is calling twice once request is completed.

Issue: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/497

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMeIQ.png)

Here the api should not display in the network tab, kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the first is NOT an `OPTIONS` request?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the API gets called when doing server side rendering, then once again when the client side takes over. You can use the StateTransfer API to cache API call results

Comment: Can you please guide me how to use the state transfer APIs?

Comment: Have a look there https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-5-universal-with-transfer-state-using-angular-cli-19fe1e1d352c

Answer (score 0):

Use `TransferHttpCacheModule`.

> `TransferHttpCacheModule` installs a Http interceptor that avoids duplicate `HttpClient` requests on the client, for requests that were already made when the application was rendered on the server side.

See [the official documentation](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md).

Answer (score 0):

I did a repo https://github.com/intergleam/universal-starter/

Just import TransferHttpCacheModule into AppModule and use HttpClient

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3').subscribe(result => {
      this.message = result;
    });
  }
```